# Javascript code won't crossfade

Tags: javascript, css

I have some Javascript code that I got from codepen.io. But I'm having a tough time executing it, although it is the same exact code. I'm just learning Javascript so I am a beginner. I didn't use HTML, I just used CSS & Javascript. The background image does shuffle through, but the fade does not work.

Here is my CSS snippet:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url(/image1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

Here is the JS that goes with it.

```
var bgImageArray = ["image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg"],
base = "/",
secs = 4;
bgImageArray.forEach(function(img){
    new Image().src = base + img; 
    // caches images, avoiding white flash between background replacements
});

function backgroundSequence() {
    window.clearTimeout();
    var k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < bgImageArray.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            document.documentElement.style.background = "url(" + base + bgImageArray[k] + ") no-repeat center center fixed";
            document.documentElement.style.backgroundSize ="cover";
        if ((k + 1) === bgImageArray.length) { setTimeout(function() { backgroundSequence() }, (secs * 1000))} else { k++; }            
        }, (secs * 1000) * i)   
    }
}
backgroundSequence();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Improper use of `clearTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you defined the CSS rules to the `body` but in your JavaScript, the new images are attached to documentElement, which is equal to `html` tag and not to `body` tag.

Try changing these lines:

```
document.documentElement.style.background = "url(" + base + bgImageArray[k] + ") no-repeat center center fixed";
document.documentElement.style.backgroundSize ="cover";
```

to this:

```
document.body.style.background = "url(" + base + bgImageArray[k] + ") no-repeat center center fixed";
document.body.style.backgroundSize ="cover";
```

Just changed `documentElement` with `body`

Answer (score 0):

You should change `document.documentElement` to `document.body` and you can remove `window.clearTimeout`

You can see this demo for working:

http://codepen.io/dangvanthanh/pen/NGpqYr

Comment: Not sure how to follow this.. can you explain some more?